# Cжатие большого текста в TextView

Tags: android, view, textview, width

Всем привет! У меня появился небольшой вопрос по TextView. Время от времени мне нужно вставлять в него текст разной длины, также периодически я изменяю параметры его ширины.В чем проблема? Вот в чем. Когда мне нужно вставить строчку на подобие этой "abcdefgh_myword" в маленький TextView, я получаю что-то вроде этого "abcdefg" . меня это естественно не удовлетворяет и я хоте бы получить что-то вроде такого: "..._myword". Решение этой проблемы я видел в том чтобы как то уметь считать кол-во текста который видит пользователь и соответственно его менять, но как это сделать я еще не понял.

На английском **stackoverflow** мне порекомендовали использовать атрибут *android:ellipsize="start"*
Я попробывал и вот что выходит...

До сужения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После сужения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите не совсем то чего я бы хотел..

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="abcdef1234567" />
```

Есть у кого нибудь идеи как достичь требуемого результата?

Comment: я не вижу разницы между тем, что хотите получить вы и что изображено на скриншоте, то есть я не вижу, что это не совсем то, что вы хотели. Чем именно вас не устраивает предложенное решение?

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. Сделайте так:

```
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ваш текст"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

Вы должны указать ширину вашего текст вью, например `100dp`, чтобы весь вводимый текст не превышал эту ширину, затем указать максимальное количество линий, у нас 1. Затем где `ellipsize` вы указываете `start`, текст будет отрубаться с начала строки. И далее вы прописываете `singleLine` и включаете его указав `true`, silngeLine устаревший, но он работает и еще полезен.